# How to carry number from decimal to whole byte array

Tags: c#, math, binary

**Note:** This is more of a logic/math problem than a specific C# problem.

I have my own class called `Number` - it very simply contains two separate byte arrays called `Whole` and `Decimal`. These byte arrays each represent essentially an infinitely large whole number, but, when put together the idea is that they create a whole number with a decimal part.

The bytes are stored in a little-endian format, representing a number. I'm creating a method called `AddNumbers` which will add two of these `Number`s together.

This method relies on another method called `PerformAdd`, which just adds two arrays together. It simply takes in a pointer to the final byte array, a pointer to one array to add, and a pointer to the second array to add - as well as the length of each of them. *The two arrays are just named "larger" and "smaller"*. Here is the code for this method:

```
    private static unsafe void PerformAdd(byte* finalPointer, byte* largerPointer, byte* smallerPointer, int largerLength, int smallerLength)
    {
        int carry = 0;

        // Go through all the items that can be added, and work them out.
        for (int i = 0; i < smallerLength; i++)
        {
            var add = *largerPointer-- + *smallerPointer-- + carry;

            // Stick the result of this addition in the "final" array.
            *finalPointer-- = (byte)(add & 0xFF);

            // Now, set a carry from this.
            carry = add >> 8;
        }

        // Now, go through all the remaining items (which don't need to be added), and add them to the "final" - still working with the carry.
        for (int i = smallerLength; i < largerLength; i++)
        {
            var wcarry = *largerPointer-- + carry;

            // Stick the result of this addition in the "final" array.
            *finalPointer-- = (byte)(wcarry & 0xFF);

            // Now, set a carry from this.
            carry = wcarry >> 8;
        }

        // Now, if we have anything still left to carry, carry it into a new byte.
        if (carry > 0)
            *finalPointer-- = (byte)carry;
    }
```

This method isn't where the problem lies - the problem is with how I use it. It's the `AddNumbers` method that uses it. The way it works is fine - it organizes the two separate byte arrays into the "larger" (larger meaning having a higher length of bytes) and "smaller". And then it creates pointers, it does this both for `Whole` and `Decimal` separately. The problem is with the decimal part.

Let's say we're adding the numbers `1251` and `2185` together, in this situation you would get `3436` - so that works perfectly!

Take another example as well: You have the numbers `4.6` and add `1.2` - once again, this works fine, and you get `5.8`. The problem comes with the next example.

We have `15.673` and `1.783`, you would expect `17.456`, however, actually, this returns: `16.1456`, and the reason for that is because it doesn't carry the "1".

***So, this is my problem: How would I implement a way that knows when and how to do this?*** Here's the code for my `AddNumbers` method:

```
    public static unsafe Number AddNumbers(Number num1, Number num2)
    {
        // Store the final result.
        Number final = new Number(new byte[num1.Whole.Length + num2.Whole.Length], new byte[num1.Decimal.Length + num2.Decimal.Length]);

        // We're going to figure out which number (num1 or num2) has more bytes, and then we'll create pointers to smallest and largest.
        fixed (byte* num1FixedWholePointer = num1.Whole, num1FixedDecPointer = num1.Decimal, num2FixedWholePointer = num2.Whole, num2FixedDecPointer = num2.Decimal,
            finalFixedWholePointer = final.Whole, finalFixedDecimalPointer = final.Decimal)
        {
            // Create a pointer and figure out which whole number has the most bytes.
            var finalWholePointer = finalFixedWholePointer + (final.Whole.Length - 1);
            var num1WholeLarger = num1.Whole.Length > num2.Whole.Length ? true : false;

            // Store the larger/smaller whole number lengths.
            var largerLength = num1WholeLarger ? num1.Whole.Length : num2.Whole.Length;
            var smallerLength = num1WholeLarger ? num2.Whole.Length : num1.Whole.Length;

            // Create pointers to the whole numbers (the largest amount of bytes and smallest amount of bytes).
            var largerWholePointer = num1WholeLarger ? num1FixedWholePointer + (num1.Whole.Length - 1) : num2FixedWholePointer + (num2.Whole.Length - 1);
            var smallerWholePointer = num1WholeLarger ? num2FixedWholePointer + (num2.Whole.Length - 1) : num1FixedWholePointer + (num1.Whole.Length - 1);

            // Handle decimal numbers.
            if (num1.Decimal.Length > 0 || num2.Decimal.Length > 0)
            {
                // Create a pointer and figure out which decimal has the most bytes.
                var finalDecPointer = finalFixedDecimalPointer + (final.Decimal.Length - 1);
                var num1DecLarger = num1.Decimal.Length > num2.Decimal.Length ? true : false;

                // Store the larger/smaller whole number lengths.
                var largerDecLength = num1DecLarger ? num1.Decimal.Length : num2.Decimal.Length;
                var smallerDecLength = num1DecLarger ? num2.Whole.Length : num1.Decimal.Length;

                // Store pointers for decimals as well.
                var largerDecPointer = num1DecLarger ? num1FixedDecPointer + (num1.Decimal.Length - 1) : num2FixedDecPointer + (num2.Decimal.Length - 1);
                var smallerDecPointer = num1DecLarger ? num2FixedDecPointer + (num2.Decimal.Length - 1) : num1FixedDecPointer + (num1.Decimal.Length - 1);

                // Add the decimals first.
                PerformAdd(finalDecPointer, largerDecPointer, smallerDecPointer, largerDecLength, smallerDecLength);
            }

            // Add the whole number now.
            PerformAdd(finalWholePointer, largerWholePointer, smallerWholePointer, largerLength, smallerLength);
        }

        return final;
    }
```

Comment: I'd compare the number of digits of the `Decimal` parts before the addition and after and carry all new digits. `.12`(2) + `.899` (3) = `.1019` (4) so left-shift to `1.019` (3) and add the `1` to the `Whole` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need `BigDecimal` in C# I would just suggest to find and use an existing implementation. For example https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136 (I am not the author, but it seems fine).

If you HAVE to implement it for any reason (school, etc) even then I would just resort to using `BigInteger`.

If you have to implement it with byte arrays... You can still benefit from the idea of using scale. You obviously have to take any extra digits after your operations such as "PerformAdd" and then carry them over to the main number.

However problems don't stop there. When you begin implementing multiplication you will run into more issues and you will have to start to mix decimal and integer part inevitably.

`8.73*0.11 -> 0.9603
0.12*0.026 -> 0.00312`

As you can see integer and decimal parts mix up and then decimal part grows into a longer sequence

however if you represent these as:

`873|2 * 11|2 -> 873*11|4 -> 9603|4 -> 0.9603
12|2 & 26|3 -> 12*26|5 -> 312|5 -> 0.00312`

these problems disappear.

Comment: One thing that is a bit annoying about using BigInteger and that BigDecimal class is that they always want to parse strings and convert to strings - not to character arrays, which would slow down performance... This BigDecimal doesn't have a parse anyway, but I can probably get around that just by exposing `_unscaledValue` and `_scale` and just implementing the two methods myself I guess. Also, any idea why BigInteger [uses a uint array](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,138c40647d26f1fc) instead of a byte array? (Just curious)

Comment: The problem with the linked implementation is that it does not implement any of the really hard stuff i.e. the arithmetic operations themselves. I'm not sure how you can use a `BigDecimal` that you can't add or multiply. And AFAIK there is no widely used implementation that you can rely on. This is probably because built-in `decimal` is enough for most of the money-related problems and if you do some hardcore computations, you probable want to use some faster (i.e. C++) implantation with more features anyway like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: @ABPerson, I believe that `uint` is used instead of `byte` for performance reasons. On most of the target platforms multiplying two `uint`s into a `ulong` will take just 1 CPU instruction so it will be like 4 times faster than with `byte` to handle the same amount of data.

Comment: As for `string` vs `char[]` I think the moment you start doing parsing/ToString stuff, the performance difference becomes negligible. `string` doesn't add that much of the overhead comparing to a lot of arithmetic operations you have to do. I will be really surprised if you can notice a difference in anything beyond purely synthetic tests.

Comment: In response to the first comment (that's a lot of comments), I was just saying implementing the `Parse` and `ToString` myself (which I do actually already have the code for), and leaving the rest up to the `BigDecimal` - since I do already have the code to do that (from my previous implementation) - also, the `BigDecimal` doesn't even have a `Parse` method anyway, so I'd have to make one anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The format you selected is fundamentally hard to use and I'm not aware of anyone who uses the same format for this task. For example, multiplication or division in that format must be very hard to implement.

Actually I don't think you store enough information to uniquely restore the value in the first place. How in your format stored representations are different for `0.1` and `0.01`? I don't think you can distinguish those two values.

The issue you are facing is a lesser side-effect of the same problem: you store binary representations for decimal values and expect to be able to imply unique size (number of digits) of the *decimal* representation. You can't do it because when decimal overflow happens you are not guaranteed to get an overflow in your 256-based stored value as well. Actually it is more often not to happen simultaneously.

I don't think you can resolve this issue in any other way than explicitly storing something equivalent to the number of digits after the decimal point. And if you are going to do that anyway, why not switch to a much simpler format of a single [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2) (yes, it is a part of the standard library although there is nothing like `BigDecimal`) and a `scale`? This is the format used by many similar libraries. In that format `123.45` is stored as pair of `12345` and `-2` (for decimal position) while `1.2345` is stored as a pair of `12345` and `-4`. Multiplication in that format is almost a trivial task (given that `BigInteger` already implements multiplication, so you just need to be able to truncate zeros at the end). Addition and subtraction are less trivial but what you need is first match the scales of the two numbers using multiplication by 10, then use standard addition over `BigInteger` and then normalize back (remove zeros at the end). Division is still hard and you have to decide what rounding strategies you want support because division of two numbers is not guaranteed to fit into a number of a fixed precision.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling right from the start that I really wasn't doing it right... There is actually a `BigRational` library, and that was what I started using but it really didn't seem to work. I'll mark your answer as the answer soon if nothing else comes along.

Comment: Also, I was well aware of the thing with `0.1` and `0.01` before I posted to question - *originally* I was probably just going to have an integer to represent the amount of "0"s after the decimal place.